# Limit tends to infinity $\lim_{x \to \infty}\sqrt{x^2+x}+2\sqrt{x^2+2x}-x$

Tags: limits, radicals

$\lim_{x \to \infty}\sqrt{x^2+x}+2\sqrt{x^2+2x}-x$

I tried multiply the conjugate and can't work out. Please advise

Answer (score 3):

It blows up: the first term is larger than $x$, and the second is larger than $2x$, so the whole thing is larger than $3x-x=2x$. (The lesson here is not to get so bound up in technique that you forget to think about what’s actually going on!)

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I guess the either the textbook is wrong or my memory failed. I wonder if this exists at first, but I remembered the answer was -3/2, so.

Comment: @Paul: You’re welcome. My guess is that either there was a typo in the problem, or you misremembered it.

Comment: $$\text{- It blows up...}$$
$$\text{- Take cover!}$$

Comment: @Peter: $$\huge\text{B}\infty\text{M}$$